# predicting electric fields via regression using unet architecture gives bad results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

**Task**: Predict a discretized electric field to a given chip-design using a unet-architeture

**Training data**:
*chip-design*: 2D/3D array with binary values (i.e. 0 and 4.1, which stay the same for a whole dataset. Only there position for each design will change) (imagine a chessboard)
*e-field*: 2D/3D array with 6 ***very small*** values (discretized real & imaginary value of the e-field for x-,y-,z-component at the given position in the 2D/3D space)

I fed my model a lot of this data-pairs (chipdesign + e-fields): ~300.000 Pairs
Shown below you can see the mean of means, the min and max value for the 6 values over all the 300.000 e-field arrays.
[mean of means, overall min & max of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixsml.png)

**Goal**: Train model with lots of design/efield pairs -> input design and predict e-field
: [2D-example true and prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hE9a.png)

**Architeture & hyper parametres**: I tried to get results with Relu and leaky-ReLu. Different loss functions (mae, mse, huber), with and without batch normalization. Optimizer was always Adam (didnt touch the default learning parametres). Epochs ranging from 100-2000-5000, whereas the loss drastically decreased after 50 epoches and then stayed rougly the same.

The 2D architecture was looking the same with just equivalent the 2D-functions.

```
def conv_block(input, num_filters, padding):
    x=Conv3D(num_filters, 3, strides=(2,2,2), padding=padding)(input)
    # x=Activation('relu')(x)
    x=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
    return x

def encoder_block(input, num_filters, padding):
    g=Conv3D(num_filters, 3, strides=(2,2,2), padding=padding)(input)
    # g = BatchNormalization()(g)
    # g=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(g)
    g=Activation('relu')(g)
    return g

def decoder_block(input, skip_features, num_filters, padding):
    g=Conv3DTranspose(num_filters, 3, strides=(2,2,2), padding=padding)(input)
    # g = BatchNormalization()(g)
    g=Concatenate()([g, skip_features])
    # g=LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(g)
    g=Activation('relu')(g)
    return g

def build_unet(input_shape):
    input = Input(input_shape)

    p1 = encoder_block(input, 32,'same')
    p2 = encoder_block(p1, 64, 'same')
    p3 = encoder_block(p2, 128,'same')
    b1 = conv_block(p3, 256, 'same')
    d2 = decoder_block(b1, p3, 128,'same')
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, p2, 64, 'same')
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, p1, 32, 'same')

    outputs = Conv3DTranspose(6, (3,3,3),strides=(2,2,2), padding="same", activation="linear")(d4)
    

    model = Model(input, outputs, name="U-Net")
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.summary()
    return model
```

**Predicting 3D:** Somehow the results are very bad. Whenever I print the prediction like in the 2D- example above, I get results like this for 50 epoches: [plane of the 3D e-field array for the real y values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imjxd.png). For the x-, z-values the prediction looks the same.
Somehow all the values converge to one point. Whenever I train my model for like 2000 epoches the results look like this: [2000 epoches prediction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xjMX.png)

I really dont know why I got such bad results for the 3D-Unet. Do you think I need to rescale the e-field values? They are already in this range of [-1,1], but more like [-0.0000x,0.0000x].

Comment: This kind of thing really needs actual analysis of the results (looking at failure examples, distributions  of the loss as a function of different paramaters such as spatial location, meta-data, etc., etc.). But one simple note is that if you have binary data, you should probably normalized it to 0-1 values and use a BCE loss...

Comment: Thanks! Only my input is kind of binary. The prediction should consist of values (in the case above) in a range of [-e-5,e-5]. BCE is a lossfunction for classification problems, am i wrong?